# mysql query finding parent from children records

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child

I have two tables.  One has assemblies (Assembly) and the other table has components (Component).  A specific set of components creates an assembly.  Some assemblies need multiple copies of a component.  Some components can be used in different assemblies.  There are no more than eight (8) distinct components per assembly.

I created a joining table AssemblyComponent that creates the "recipes" for assemblies.

I want to be able to come up with the assembly based upon a set of components.  If the components do not match any assembly a NULL should be returned.

```
Assembly
assemblyid INT

Component
componentid INT

AssemblyComponent
assemblyid INT
componentid INT
numberofcomponents INT
```

So the goal is to have a stored procedure that would take a variable number of components and return the assembly( should only be one for a given set of components) that fit the component set.  I am using mysql 5.1.x so I cannot pass an array to the stored procedure.  I would just create eight IN parameters and set the unused ones to NULL.

I am more interested in what query approach to use as opposed to actually writing the procedure code at this time.  If my table structure needs to be changed, I can do that too.  Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: 1> do you consider it a match if the list of components specified is a subset? e.g. 4 components specified as input and they match an assembly that has 5 components. 2> Is number of components considered in matching?

Comment: 1.  No.  The amount of components and types must match.

Comment: 2.  Yes the number is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** this query is very important part of the application and you are willing to modify the schema and application code to make this query work efficiently and cleanly, I would suggest that you modify `AssemblyComponent` table. Make one row of the table represent one `assemblyid`. Add 16 columns - 8 for `componentid` and 8 for respective `numberofcomponents`.

```
**AssemblyComponent**
assemblyid INT
componentid1 INT
numberofcomponents1 INT
componentid2 INT
numberofcomponents2 INT
....
```

At the time of insert/update into this table you have to ensure that `componentid`s are sorted from left to right in a row. While querying you have to again ensure that componentid parameters are sorted similarly. Now your query is a simple `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause such as :

```
WHERE
      componentid1=componentid1arg 
  AND numberofcomponents1=numberofcomponents1arg
  AND componentid2=componentid2arg 
  AND numberofcomponents2=numberofcomponents2arg
....
```

Above query needs to modified to compare nulls properly (`=` may not work for nulls). Ensuring `componentid` order can be done in code or through a stored proc.

If these changes are too much and you would rather have a simple schema and deal with a complex stored proc while doing the matching, then a different approach needs to be taken.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  There number of assemblies is relatively small so it was easy on me and the data store.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Let's say you know the `componentid` values of the components in question.

Then you can do something like this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) matching,
         assemblyid
   WHERE componentId IN (your set of componentid values)
   GROUP BY assemblyid
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

This sort of thing will figure out how many of your componentid values turn up in each assembly, and then get the one with the most matches.